# Pandas split DataFrame when column name are in values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe that is not well formatted, it look like

```
0  1
col_name1     val1
col_name2     val2
col_name3     val3
col_name1     val4
col_name2     val5
col_name3     val6
.  .             .
.  .             .
```

and I wanted to make it look like

```
col_name1,col_name2,col_name3
val1,val2,val3
val4,val5,val6
```

How can I split it that way?

I tried to transpose the dataframe and didn't work the same for some groupby manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

**Original DataFrame**

[image]

**STEP1:** Group the data by '1st column'

```
df_temp = df.groupby(0)[1].apply(list)
```

**STEP2:** **Get column names** for new data frame:

```
col_names = df_temp.index
```

**STEP3:** **Get row values** and store it in a list:

```
row_values = df_temp.values.tolist()
```

**STEP4:** **Make new data frame** in desired format:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(row_values, columns=  col_names)
new_df = new_df.T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
m=df.groupby('0')['1'].apply(list)
df1=pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),index=m.index).T.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print(df1)
```

---

```
  col_name1 col_name2 col_name3
0      val1      val2      val3
1      val4      val5      val6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = {i:[] for i in list(set(df["0"]))}
for i in range(len(df)):
    new_df[df["0"][i]].append(df["1"][i])
```

---

```
Result
col_name2 col_name3 col_name1
0      val2      val3      val1
1      val5      val6      val4
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order of rows is consistent, you can just pivot your dataframe after adding a new pseudo-index with `int(index / 3)`:

```
df['ndx'] = (df.index / 3).astype(int)
df = df.pivot(index='ndx', columns='0', values='1')
```

If unsure, this will be more robust provided `col_name1` comes always first:

```
df['ndx'] = pd.Series(np.where(df['0'] == 'col_name1', df.index, np.nan),
                      index = df.index).fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
df = df.pivot(index='ndx', columns='0', values='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index([df.groupby(0).cumcount(), 0])[1].unstack().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  col_name1 col_name2 col_name3
0      val1      val2      val3
1      val4      val5      val6
```