# Pandas | Split/sort dataframe row names into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe here:

```python
    0      1
0  col_a   0
1  col_b   2
2  col_c   3
3  col_a   4
4  col_b   5
5  col_c   6
```

Each row at column zero holds a specific value. I would like to turn the rows into columns I can index like so:

```python
  col_a  col_b  col_c
0     1      2      3
1     4      5      6
```

I've tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166443/15324861) answer, but I can't get it to output. Thank you in advance.

Duplicate didn't help. So I updated it.

Comment: Can you provide a larger example in case the duplicate doesn't help?

Comment: Then please post the code that you tried and how it failed